# Elements not aligning in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I would like for each icon to align with their respective heading.
But this is what it looks like instead:

[image]

**CSS HTML**:

```css
.section-service .bx h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #535355;
}

.section-service .bx span {
    font-size: 250%;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
.section-service .bx h4,
.section-service .bx p {
   float: right;
    width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<html>        
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/responcive.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
</html>

<section id="service" class="section-service">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>our service</h2>
                <p class="long-copy">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row  js--wp-2">
                <div class="col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-desktop"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>web development</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-paw"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>digital desighn</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-magic"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>marketing</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>e-commerce</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-mobile-phone"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>app development</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-rocket"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>s.e.o</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I tried to make this section in ***responsive ,I'll try and fix 
992px and 768px media queries***. I could not fix it in ***<=568px***.

Comment: What is the problem? The screen shot looks like fine!

Comment: @sємsєм font are not align with their respective heading, see my snippet

Comment: I think he means the icon font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think your `h4` elements have a `margin-top`.*

You should add '`col-xs-12`' class before '`col-sm-4`'. 
Something like  :

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bx">`

*Maybe just remove this margin-top will do the trick...*

```
.section-service .bx h4{
   margin-top:0px;
}
```

*or add to this existing selector :*

```
.section-service .bx h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #535355;
    margin-top:0px;  // <-- this line
}
```

*Maybe you've got too an other css file who override this margin-top.

So you just have to append a `!important` like this :*

```
margin-top:0px !important;
```

**Snipet** :

```css
.section-service .bx h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #535355;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.section-service .bx span {
    font-size: 250%;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
.section-service .bx h4,
.section-service .bx p {
   float: right;
    width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<html>        
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/responcive.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
</html>

<section id="service" class="section-service">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>our service</h2>
                <p class="long-copy">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row  js--wp-2">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-desktop"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>web development</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-paw"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>digital desighn</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-magic"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>marketing</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>e-commerce</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-mobile-phone"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>app development</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bx">
                    <span class="fa fa-rocket"></span>
                    <div>
                        <h4>s.e.o</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknowns printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

*Here is a **[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/D7jGgqj9LC)** to experiment : http://www.bootply.com/D7jGgqj9LC , you can click on the phone icon to test in smartphone view.*

Comment: add 'col-xs-12' is necessary for the small screen view.can u explain.

Comment: The 'float' and 'div size' for 'sm' are set up in media query '@media (min-width: 768px)' ...
So every thing under this resolution, is considered as a simple div, not floating to left....

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.section-service .bx h4, .section-service .bx p {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```