# Do I need to write col-xs-12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I usually don't use `col-xs-12` class just write `div class= 'col-md-9`' 
But I just saw in someone's code `<div class='col-md-9 col-xs-12'>`
so i thought it is the default behaviour and I don't neeed it.

Comment: It isn't necessary to write col-xs-12, you are right.

Comment: col-xs-12 will take complete row as a column in the extra small device, and for col-md-9 will take 9 column in a row in medium device so it is basically how you want to show the same column in specific device.

Comment: Sometimes , the fact to don't set the col-xs-xx can be problematic : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36681598/2454790